# php Zend Framework - Changing a decorator only if it hasn't been changed already

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I'm actually looking for a nice way to have generic decorators for all my forms elements but at the same time being able to change some decorators of some elements very specifically.

Say i want all my elements to have new generic decorators. I would do that in the `addElement` method of my parent generic form class. For example in `My_Form` class extending `Zend_Form` wich would be extended by a `My_Form_User` containing actual elements declarations, i would have something like :

```
public function addElement($element, $name = null, $options = null)
{
    parent::addElement($element, $name, $options);

    if (! is_object($element)) {
        $element = $this -> getElement($name);
    }

    if (is_object($element))
    {
        $element -> clearDecorators();
        $element -> addDecorators($this -> elementDecorators);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Now, i have very specific needs on some elements of some forms. So i set these decorators when i create the element (in `My_Form_User` class) but, of course, when i add them to the form with `addElement`, i can't find of a way to check if 1 decorator (`ViewHelper` or `Description` or `Label`...) has been modified so that i don't erase it with the generic one.

Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit short, but ...

- getDecorator($name)
- getDecorators()
- removeDecorator($name)

...maybe this helps already.

Comment: Actually if i do a getDecorator($name) i will always have something as the Zend default decorators are loaded right ?

Comment: Well if you want to preserve or remove decorators you should know which ones, right? So does it make a difference if those are default or not?

Comment: If i take back my example, in My_Form class (not My_Form_User), i don't know wich elements have specific decorators ; it's exactly the point of my question, i'd like a way to know that :)

Comment: `getDecorators()` should give you the knowledge about the decorators of each element. Then you know. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: yes it will give me all the decorators, but in `My_Form` i want to set generic decorators and i only want to do that if the decorators haven't been changed already from the Zend default ones. Maybe i'm missing something here, but there is no `getDefaultDecorators()` or `getDefaultDecorator($name)` to check if it is different than the actual `getDecorator($name)`.

Comment: I always thought the default decorators differ in their name. If it's not possible to distinguish based on name, I suspect you then need to interfere with the base class and intercept the decorator registration, set a point when the default phase has been done and mark any additional decorator as non-default.

Comment: I guess i'll have to do deeper changes as you suggest yes. Or maybe it's whole way i'm taking the problem that is not good. I'm up to all suggestions. Thanks hakre.